# multi_index index member of sub class member

Tags: boost, multi-index

I am having problem to define a subclass member as index member
Is this possible
For the following code

```
namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

struct UsersKey {
    uint64_t IMSI;
};

struct UsersVal {
    uint64_t IMSI;
};

struct HashEntry{
    UsersKey key;
    UsersVal val;
}

typedef bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<struct IMSI_tag>,  bmi::member<HashEntry, uint64_t , &HashEntry::UsersKey::IMSI>,  boost::hash<uint64_t>, std::equal_to<uint64_t> > hashed_by_IMSI;


typedef 
  bmi::indexed_by<  hashed_by_IMSI > UsersKey_hash_indices;

 typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<
      HashEntry,
      UsersKey_hash_indices>
    > GlobalHash;
```

I get the following error

```
error: no member named 'UsersKey' in 'HashEntry'; did you mean simply 'UsersKey'?
```

Here is a link to online code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d736557edf615fc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ pointer to member function syntax does not allow to designate members inside members as you intend to do here. One simple option is to use the provided [`global_fun`](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#global_fun) key extractor as shown at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c57625bfb1d5acfa

Best,